# Failed Load myclass-context.xml in junit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, junit, junit4

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class Myclass extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
{   
    @Test
    public final void testHandleRequestView() throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        //some testing codes
     }
}
```

When I run junit testing for this kind of class it gave me error "Failed to load Application Context"

It search file called "**Myclass-context.xml**"

I don't need any configuration file for this, What is the reason for this and how do i sole this? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need a Spring context, why have you used those annotations and base class?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify context xml as part of @ContextConfiguraiton

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("Myclass-context.xml")
public class Myclass extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
{   
    @Test
    public final void testHandleRequestView() throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        //some testing codes
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a Spring context for your tests, you shouldn't have your test case extending a ContextTest.

`extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` is not required.